# How to create SQL Server tree in one row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
create table Test 
(
    Id int identity, 
    Name varchar(50) not null, 
    SName varchar(50) null, 
    ParentId int null 
)

 insert into Test 
  values ('aaa', 'bbb', null), ('adf', '22b', null), ('aad', 'bbsd',2),('asdsaa', 'bf', 3),('sdfs','sdf',3),('iopio','uiopio',3)


select * from Test
```

I have a table with `parentid`, and I want to get something like that

```
Name SName "aaa" "bbb" , "adf" {"aad":{"asdsaa":"bf"}}
```

from the selected values

I have been trying to get it with a recursive query, but...

```
WITH tree_view AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Id, ParentId, Name, SName 
    FROM 
        Test
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        parent.Id, parent.ParentId, parent.Name, parent.SName 
    FROM 
        Test parent 
    JOIN 
        tree_view tv ON parent.ParentId = tv.Id 
)
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM tree_view
```

I want to get this

[image]

if the parent id is not null, in one sell I want to get Name:SName in Sname field

Comment: Please read some articles how to ask good questions on SO. Here is one how to create tables https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post, here how to format code https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and here some general hints how to create a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What you want is not clear.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use PIVOT:
Below is similar solution which you can try

Sample Table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable](
[Id] [int] NULL,
[Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Description] [nvarchar](50) NULL)
```

Inserting sample values:

```
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (1,'Test1a','TestDesc1a')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (2,'Test1b','TestDesc1b')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (3,'Test2a','TestDesc2a')
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES (4,'Test2b','TestDesc2b')
```

Query to get the desired output using Pivot:

```
SELECT  'Name' AS [Column], [1], [2],[3],[4]
FROM
(SELECT Name, id from TestTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(Max(Name) FOR ID IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])) AS PT

UNION

SELECT  'Description' AS [Column], [1], [2],[3],[4]
FROM
(SELECT  id,[Description] from TestTable) AS ST
PIVOT
(Max([Description]) FOR ID IN ([1], [2],[3],[4])) AS PT
ORDER BY [Column] DESC
```

OutPut:

```
Column         1           2          3           4
Name           Test1a      Test1b     Test2a      Test2b
Description    TestDesc1a  TestDesc1b TestDesc2a  TestDesc2b
```

Hope this helps to solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you ar sure any parent leads to only 1 leaf, it's possible to generate the JSON you want by playing only with string manipulation:

```
with rel_hier(id, parentid, name, sname, js) as (
    select m.id, m.parentid, m.name, m.sname, 
        CAST(CASE WHEN m.parentid IS NULL THEN 
        CONCAT('"' , m.sname , '"') ELSE 
        CONCAT('{"' ,  m.name , '" : "' , m.sname , '"}')  END AS VARCHAR(2000)) 
        js
    from Test m
    where not exists(select 1 from Test t1 where t1.parentid = m.id) 
    
    union all
    
    select m.id, m.parentid, m.name, m.sname, 
        CAST(CASE WHEN m.parentid IS NULL THEN r.js ELSE CONCAT('{"' , m.name , 
          '" : ' , r.js , '}') END AS VARCHAR(2000)) js
    from rel_hier r 
    join Test m on m.id = r.parentid
)
SELECT name, js as sname FROM rel_hier r
WHERE parentid IS NULL
;


name    sname
aaa "bbb"
adf {"aad" : {"asdsaa" : "bf"}}
```

But you should also better explain the substitution rules for a number of levels > 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, but
its don't work  if we have more than 1 child,  if we have 3 child it shows three-row,  but must be one 
name    sname
aaa  "bbb"
adf  {"aad" : {"asdsaa" : "bf","sdfs" : "sdf","asdsaa" : "bf"}}
or 
it can be like that
colName
"aaa": "bbb"
"adf": {"aad" : {"asdsaa" : "bf","sdfs" : "sdf","asdsaa" : "bf"}}

Comment: Then provide better test data and complete specifications.